# Update Clojure map that is wrapped inside an atom

Tags: clojure

I am trying to update a map that is inside an atom. Each map is referenced by a value.

```
(def a (atom {}))

(defn foo [id mps]
  (let [x (merge (get mps id) mps)]
    (swap! a assoc id x) x))

(foo 2 {:baz 88}) => {:baz 88}

@a => {2 {:baz 88}}

(foo 2 {:bar 99}) => {:bar 99} ??

@a => {2 {:bar 99}} ??
```

It appears to be overwriting the map instead of updating it. The result I am looking for is:

```
(foo 2 {:baz 88}) => {:baz 88}

@a => {2 {:baz 88}}

(foo 2 {:bar 99}) => {:bar 99, :baz 88}

@a => {2 {:bar 99, :baz 88}}
```

Any help would be great

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are replacing the old value with the new one (using `assoc`).  what you are looking for, is the behaviour of `merge-with` (http://conj.io/store/v1/org.clojure/clojure/1.7.0-alpha4/clj/clojure.core/merge-with/) directly on the atom. Like:

```
user=> (def a (atom {}))
#'user/a
user=> (swap! a #(merge-with merge % {:a {:b 1}}))
{:a {:b 1}}
user=> (swap! a #(merge-with merge % {:a {:c 2}}))
{:a {:c 2, :b 1}}
```

Comment: `assoc-in` should work as well. It creates all nonexisting keys.